# Added a "APNS Production Certificate" type certificate,but got one type of "Apple Push Service",why?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My APNS certificate is going to expired .I revoked the old one in member center,then added a new one.But the type is "Apple Push Service" not "APNS" . Why? More over, I received the inform mail from apple about the revoked certificate. But the old certificate still works,I'm confused. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses member center to create an  Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate ,the type is "Apple Push Service". The certificate can be used to connect to both gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195  and gateway.push.apple.com:2195 . It is universal.

---- App Distribution Guide ->Creating a Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate